# Agile requirement fo continuous integration?

Tags: continuous-integration

Taking a indepth look at CI and a question rose up. Is a agile development process a pre-requisite to be able to work with Continuous Integration?

Would it be possible to implement a CI process in a traditional, team based 
development process?

Gut feeling says me that agility is more or less a pre-requisite, but "gut feeling" is not an argument when talking to management... :-)

And is there any documentation out there about this? All I found take it for granted
that you already work agile.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that continuous integration is good practice in almost all development teams, whether you are following an agile process or not (along with source control and free coffee). I've used it in agile teams, traditional teams and when I am coding alone - it has always added value.

For any development process, CI gives you:

- Immediate feedback on any build errors (e.g. when a developer has forgotten to add or check in a file)
- Immediate feedback on unit test failures (if you have written unit tests, which again are a good idea whether you are following an agile process or not)
- Your QA team having up to date binaries to test with
- Automating the build process (which greatly reduces the chances of error when you release your software)

Have a look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) - it's free and pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

CI is not really related to agile or not-agile methodology (although some state to require it, while others just indirectly imply it or not mention at all)

CI is the only tool (yeah suppose it like a keyboard) which helps you during development to eliminate some bugs ASAP

actually the only thing you need to do CI is configure version control system with some build tool (like post-commit hook), and ask all developers to commit/fetch code as soon they pretty sure that it will compile - this will be enough to start continuous integration, then of course you can add unit test etc

so, the answer - **agile is not requirement and you can implement CI in any process**, without implementing XP, Scrum, Whatever methodology